# How to pass warnings outside of functions as exceptions, but without program interruption

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that implements a model and a view.

I want the model to do some processing and return a warning to the view if something didn't go right.

Now, I want the warning to be passed around as sort of an exception, so if I have a GUI as a view, I can easily create a Message Box or something similar to that to show the warning, but without interrupting program flow.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Note: I am aware of the `warnings` module in Python, but I do not know if I can pass those warnings as exceptions that don't interrupt program flow.

Relevant code:

```py
class Model():

   def __init__(self):
      try:
         with open(some_file) as file:
            self.file = file.readlines()
      except FileNotFoundError:
         # I don't want the Model to print the message here
         # print("Warning: File not found, continuing with defaults")
         # I want a warning to be passed up to the view
         self.file = 'some piece of data'
         raise FileNotFoundError(error_msg)
```

```py
class View():

   def __init__(self):
      try:
         self.model = Model()
      except FileNotFoundError:
         # I want to catch the warning here and display it
         # but if I catch an exception here, Python will complain that
         # self.model was not initialized correctly when I use it later
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a `logging` and means of displaying the log in a view.

Answer (score -1):

Exceptions are used to delegate error handling, not communicate with a caller. Instead of re-raising the exception, add another attribute to the object indicating whether the data in the `file` attribute is hard-coded or not.

For example,

```
class Model():

   def __init__(self):
      self.hard_coded = False
      try:
         with open(some_file) as file:
            self.file = file.readlines()
      except FileNotFoundError:
         self.source = True
         self.file = 'some piece of data'


class View():

   def __init__(self):
       self.model = Model()
       if self.hard_coded:
           print("Warning: File not found, continuing with defaults")
```

Alternatively, you can use an `error_msg` attribute whose value is either `None` or a string for the view to print when it isn't `None`.